# How to perform logical operations OR on list [multiple elements]?

Tags: python, list, logical-operators, any

Is there any way to compare the list elements and return the outcome value ?
Below is the python snippet, where it recieves two values and returns the value.

```
def logical_or_decision(a,b):
    return a or b

value = logical_or_decision(1,0)
print value
```

I need to make it generic & scalable to more than 2 elements.How can i do it for more than 2 elements ?

Comment: Do you want to return strictly `True` or `False`, or (in case of `or`) the first truthy value of the list, as `a or b or c or ...` would?

Answer (score 4):

There's a built-in function that does this: `any`.

```
>>> any([0,0,1,0])
True

>>> any([0,0,0])
False
```

Comment: And the "and" equivalent `all`.

Comment: what if there are 3 elements like this 0,1,-1 ? say i've a list of [0,-1] , it should return -1. if [0,0,-1] , it should return -1

Comment: @Jackie what does `-1` represent? What other inputs are you using?

Comment: no, only three inputs. I mean to represent  three possible states, success,failure and unknown. 0, 1 , -1

Comment: @Jackie that's not at all what the question said. Ask a new question with *all* information in it; editing this one would make 5 answers invalid. Include some example input/output - what you expect the function to return for some given input.

Answer (score 3):

best solution ^^above^^:

```
any([True, False, True])
# returns True
```

`any` is good because "short-circuits" (like "boolean fast evaluation" it doesn't iterate till the end).

If you want things alike but manually and eager - see [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html?highlight=functools%20reduce#functools.reduce):

```
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce

reduce(or_, [True, False, True])
# returns True
```

Comment: `any()` isn't lazy, it just short-circuits. Its laziness will depend on the iterable you have passed to it as argument.

Comment: Yes, your are quite right. I mean `any` is "lazy" in terms of "generator lazy evaluation" and "boolean fast evaluation" — stops at first `True` element - it doesn't iterate till the end.

Comment: True, but the correct term for that is short-circuiting. Lazyness is something you would related to for example generators, they can pause their execution and would return result to you on demand not all of them at once. Here `any()` has no idea about the item passed to it, it just iterates over it one by one. Hence it completely depends on the iterable passed to it.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `reduce` to do it:

```
def logical_or_decision(*args):
    return reduce(
        lambda a, b: a or b,
        args,
        False
    )

print logical_or_decision(1, 1, 1, 0) # False
```

Of course you could use `any` or `all` (for logical `AND`), but `reduce` could provide you the general way to build such operations (not for `OR` or `AND`).

Comment: You may want to use it with operators available in [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.or_) rather than using `lambda`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Note that `operator.or_` is `|`, not `or`.

Comment: @tobias_k Oops! my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The builtin function [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any) would be the correct way to go about this:

```
def logical_or_decision(*args):
    return any(args)

value = logical_or_decision(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) 
print value
```

The relevant part from the link to the official documentation above:

> Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def any(iterable):
>    for element in iterable:
>        if element:
>            return True
>    return False
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible interpretations of the question:

## 1. OR & AND operations for all the elements of an iterable:

**OR:** `any`

**AND:** `all`

```
l1 = [True, False, False, True]
t1 = (True, True, True)
t2 = (False, False, False, False)

any(l1)  # True
all(l1)  # False
any(t1)  # True
all(t1)  # True
any(t2)  # False
all(t2)  # False
```

## 2. OR & AND operations for multiple pairs given as two iterables:

In this case the functions used are the same but you need to use the map and zip function to wrap them:

```
l = [True, True, False]
t = (True, False, False)

list(map(any, zip(l, t)))   # [True, True, False]
tuple(map(all, zip(l, t)))  # (True, False, False)
```

***NOTE:*** I've used lists and tuples to prove that it can be done with different array-like structures. The list and tuple wrapper in the second example is Python3 as map returns an iterator instead of a list and that would give a non-human-readable answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237153/how-to-perform-logical-operations-or-on-list-multiple-elements/41239375#comment69675004_41237241):

> say i've a list of [0,-1] , it should return -1. if [0,0,-1] , it should return -1

While most suggest using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), this does not seem to be what you actually want:

```
>>> lst1 = [0, False, [], -1, ""]
>>> lst2 = [4, True, "", 0]
>>> any(lst1)
True
>>> all(lst2)
False
```

Instead, you can use the [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) builtin (or in Python 3: `functools.reduce`) together with an accordant `lambda` function, applying `or` or `and` to the operands, to get the first ["truthy" or "falsy"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth) value in the list:

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a or b, lst1)
-1
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a and b, lst2)
''
```

Also, [`operator.or_`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.or_) and [`and_`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.and_) won't work, as those are bitwise `|` and `&` instead of logical `or` and `and`.

```
>>> reduce(operator.or_, lst1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'list'
>>> lst = [1, 2, 4]
>>> reduce(operator.or_, lst)
7
```